# C code written on a mac porting to windows

Tags: .net, c

We have a source code written in C which is meant to be use in different app. We already have an application written for mac OSX.

Now we'd like to write an app in windows (prolly using c#/.net) and reuse the same library. Not sure what it would take to be able to call those C function in a windows platform.

Since I have the source code, can I just create a DLL in windows and use it via p/invoke in my .net application?

Any pointers is helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

P/Invoke is definitely an option. Additionally, you can use C++/CLI to wrap the native C code into a CLR compatible .dll.

The only sticking point would be to ensure your C source has no implementation / OS specific code.

Comment: What do you mean by C++/CLI wrap?

Comment: @pdiddy C++/CLI can handle both native and managed code at the same time. Therefore, you can (with some work) paste much of your C code within a managed type in C++/CLI and consume it with any other .NET language.

Comment: Would you have an example of this?

Comment: Not offhand.. and the explanation would be much longer than a comment here. I'll have leave that research up to you. There are plenty of examples if you search for C++CLI native interop